# Statistical tests on zero-inflated samples

Tags: hypothesis-testing, zero-inflation

I have a lot of zeros in my samples; I found the following algorithm to deal with zero-inflated data before testing them:

1. find the proportion of zeros in each subset.
2. assume that in the subset with the smallest number of zeros all zeros are true.
3. from each subset, remove the proportion of zeros equal to the proportion of zeros in the most "zero-rich" dataset.
4. run standard non-parametric stats on this modified dataset.

Is it the right way to preprocess samples before statistical testing, or should I use a different technique or avoid preprocessing samples?

Comment: For users who can see deleted posts, the comments [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/619387/247274) might be helpful.